# Plotting double series

Tags: plotting, summation, coefficients

I am new and hoping a warm welcome from this platform.

I am trying to plot the graph of double series in one variable

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} C_{k,j} \exp(- 3^k 1.5^{j} x)$$

where coefficients are defined as 
$$
\begin{align}
C_{0,0} &= 4.55672\\
C_{k,0} &= \frac{(-1)^k 3^k}{2^k \prod_{s=1}^{k}(3^s -1)}C_{0,0}\\
C_{0,j} &= \frac{(-1)^j 1.5^j}{2^j \prod_{s=1}^{j}(1.5^s-1)}C_{0,0}\\
C_{k,j} &= \frac{(-1) (3 C_{k-1,j}+1.5 C_{k,j-1})}{2(3^k 1.5^j -1)}
\end{align}
$$

So please tell me how to define these coefficients and can be recalled in the double sum.

Comment: Can you meet us halfway and write all these expressions in correct Mathematica syntax? As a next step, read [defining functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) and look up `Product` and `Sum`. Try small examples and become comfortable with these functions before tackling the big problem! Please try on your own first, based on the resources I pointed to, and then make the question specific: ask about the first speific issue you encountered. If you've never used Mathematica, then there will be a learning curve and this is too big for your very first task.

Comment: I should note that I do not expect this to be a completely trivial exercise. Things you are likely to hit: defining recursive functions, memoization, [a need for NumericQ in function definition](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502), dealing with numerical underflow and truncating the series appropriately to get a good approximation. Explaining all this is too much for one answer so we either need to know that you understand these topic, or proceed step by step with them.

Comment: Maybe I would proceed step by step, as am not much familiar about these topics.

Comment: @John Is there a typo $\Pi_{s=1}^j$ in $C_{k,0}$ definition?

Comment: @AlexTrounev yeah I have corrected

Comment: Note that `Product[a^s - 1, {s, k}]` gives `(-1)^k QPochhammer[a, a, k]`.

Comment: Just curious:  is this a probability density function?

Answer (score 2):

As an example for beginners, I give code using a block. The series converges quickly, so we can take a finite number of members (10 in this example)

```
F[n0_, x0_] := 
 Block[{n = n0, x = x0}, 
  f[n_, x_] := Sum[c[k, j]*Exp[-3^k*(3/2)^j*x], {k, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
  c[0, 0] = 4.55679; 
  c[k_, 0] := (-1)^k*3^k*c[0, 0]/2^k/Product[3^s - 1, {s, 1, k}];
  c[0, j_] := (-1)^j*(3/2)^j*
    c[0, 0]/2^j/Product[(3/2)^s - 1, {s, 1, j}];
  Table[c[k, 
     j] = (-1)*(3*c[k - 1, j] + 3/2*c[k, j - 1])/
       2/(3^k*(3/2)^j - 1), {k, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
  f[n, x]]
```

In fig. function `F[n,x]` is shown for various `n=1,2,3,4,5,6,10`

```
{Plot[Evaluate[Table[F[k, x], {k, 1, 6}]], {x, 0, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 Plot[F[10, x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]